How to docker-compose with all services behind the same IP and with their respective ports available?
I know that I can create a macvlan that gets an IP from my home router and assigns it to the various services in my docker-compose.yml, and that I can specify IPs for each of those services.  However, I want to assign 1 IP to all of the services so that their various ednpoints differ only by the exposed ports.
How can I do this?
